# Functions.php wordpress not working for stylesheets or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am making my first custom wordpress theme and am running into problems with functions.php

I am using bootstrap too so i want to include bootstrap stylesheets to wp i currently do it this way-:

```
style.css

@import url('css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('css/font-awesome.css');
```

I understand that i can use functions.php to do the same, so i wrote a custom function and tried to do it like this-:

```
functions.php

<?php
/* Theme setup */
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

/* Add bootstrap support to the Wordpress theme*/

function theme_add_bootstrap() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );

?>
```

This does not seem to work. Neither does functions.php load the wp jquery or the bootstrap.js

Can anyone shed some light onto this matter for me? I would be ever grateful. This is not a child theme its a custom theme.

Comment: WordPress already enqueues jQuery so no need to manually do `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");`

Comment: Thank you and can you also help me with my stylesheets?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48448/22599)

Comment: I actually did try with that, but didn't work for me. :/ Neither the js or css, i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I am running this on localhost @henrywright, does that make a difference? feel like wp_enqueue_scripts this doesnt work for me.

Comment: Running on localhost shouldn't matter. Perhaps try registering your scripts first. See my answer below.

Comment: Make sure that you are calling `wp_head()` and `wp_footer` in the header and footer respectively. these hooks are the ones that actually do the enqueue.

Comment: @KhalidDabjan i wasn't doing that! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering your scripts before you enqueue them. For example:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Register Bootstrap JS.
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true );
    // Enqueue Bootstrap JS.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: I've just tested and it works for me. There must be a wider issue at play here. Perhaps something to do with your set-up elsewhere?

Comment: this works after i followed Khalid's advice! thanks!